# SVG exportable from web page

Tags: html, svg

How would I make an `svg` in an `html` page downloadble directly from the browser without a round-trip to the server?

I would like the user to be able to push a button and the `svg` element from the page would be locally saved on the user's computer much like "download as" functionality.

How can I achieve this?

PS: Bear with me please:  I am somewhat slow today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a data URI, maybe like so:

```
<a target="_blank" href="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle r='30'/></svg>">Click here</a>
```

The SVG would be opened in a new window and can be saved. Of course, after clicking the link, no dialogue will pop up, but the user has to save the file manually. I'm not sure whether this can be automated further.